# Why defining a function count as more than one statement?

Tags: php, function, if-statement

I saw a strange behaviour in PHP. See this example:

```
<?php
if (true)
    function my_function(){
        echo "here";
    }

my_function();
?>
```

Running this will give an error:

> Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'my_function' (T_STRING),
>   expecting '(' on line 4

I found that the fix to this error is to add parenthesis:

```
<?php
if (true) {
    function my_function(){
        echo "here";
    }
}
my_function();
?>
```

This code will run properly.

Can you explain it? Why defining a function count as more than one statement?

Comment: it's not - although you can omit the opening bracket, only if the condition block is a one-liner, or else it leads to weird parsing errors - a reason I hate to omit it to begin with.

Comment: Sorry, by one-liner I mean, not declaring a new condition block - I mean pure execution (as in, something like `if ($foo) echo 'hi';`)

Comment: [The manual on functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php) states: *"Functions need not be defined before they are referenced, **except** when a function is conditionally defined as shown in the two examples below.

When a function is defined in a conditional manner such as the two examples shown. Its definition must be processed **prior** to being called."*

Comment: Except the function *is* being defined (albeit conditionally) before it's being called... logically there should be no difference between `if(true) function my_function() { echo "here"; }` and `if(true) { function my_function() { echo "here"; } }` ... but the first one throws a syntax error, the second works.

Comment: They should (always) be using proper bracing then @CD001 which is probably the root of the error.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner - I'm not debating that ;) ... hell, even the idea of a *conditional function* doesn't sit right with me ... but *logically* I think the OP has a point. `if($foo) echo "bar"` is fine but `if($foo) function bar() {}` isn't ... and I'm not sure *why*. Granted it's not something that I've ever attempted before but the behaviour seems ... unintuitive.

Comment: Curiously it's perfectly happy with a self-executing closure: `if(true) (function() { $s = "here"; echo $s; })();` ... if you're happy with your PHP looking remarkably like JS (O_o) - you just can't *define* the function in a one-line conditional it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Function definition is not a statement.

You asked:

> Why defining a function count as more than one statement?

It doesn't. Defining a function is not a statement.

From [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.intro.php):

> A statement can be an assignment, a function call, a loop, a conditional statement or even a statement that does nothing (an empty statement). Statements usually end with a semicolon. In addition, statements can be grouped into a statement-group by encapsulating a group of statements with curly braces. A statement-group is a statement by itself as well.

An `if` statement must be followed by another statement! Let's simplify your problem and see what are some examples of such statements as defined above:

```
if(1)
    {} // A statement-group is a statement by itself as well.
if(1)
    ; // an empty statement
if(1)
    $a=1; // an assignment
if(1)
    print(1); // a function call
if(1)
    while(0){} // a loop
if(1)
    if(0); // a conditional statement
```

A definition of function or class is not a statement per the official PHP definition. A non-statement cannot be used in the context where a statement is expected.

## When a function definition is a statement?

PHP 5.3 has introduced a concept of anonymous functions (Lambda Functions and Closures). An anonymous function definition is a statement.

The syntax of anonymous function is almost the same as the normal function definition, but you are expected to provide no name. In other words keyword `function` must be followed by `()` with only whitespace allowed between them. It must also end in semicolon.

```
// This is valid:
if(1)
    function (){};
//This is invalid:
if(1)
    function a(){}
//           ^
// syntax error, unexpected 'a' (T_STRING), expecting '('
```

This is why the error message is telling you that the name of the function is unexpected. PHP expects a statement and when it encounters `function` keyword, it expects that you are defining an anonymous function. An anonymous function doesn't have a name, so the name part is unexpected.